# Xbootclasspath and Java security

Tags: java, security

Is it feasible for malicious software to use [Xbootclasspath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard) to get round Java security?

Answer (score 1):

When malicious software can execute the Java launcher with arbitrary parameters, then it can pretty much do everything that's outside the Java security mechanism anyway.

It's effectively *outside* the Java security mechanism in that position. For example: it could just as easily start itself without a security manager at all, which would be an even easier way to "get around Java security" in such a situation.

So I don't see how this is breaking Java security.